# OS X Terminal displaying ö when typing |

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

It's the first time this has happened to me. Does anyone know why this could be happening?
I think I configured something wrong in the keyboard settings.

This is working fine in Word 2011, for example.

Comment: which keyboard layout are you using? Are you switching between multiple?

Comment: I connected an external keyboard some days ago. I should have look at settings to see what could be happening. The thing is that I need to pipe in terminal!

Comment: I'm using Spanish - ISO as input source

Comment: OK, I rebooted the computer and is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something to do with the "Automatically switch to a document's input source" option in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources, which allows you to have different output sources for different applications/tabs/documents. Simply uncheck that to only use one keyboard layout for all applications